# How is the begin() pointer created in this code snippet?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, return, conditional-operator

```
template<typename T>
T* begin(Vector<T>& x)
{
    return x.size() ? &x[0] : nullptr; // pointer to first element or nullptr
}
```

In another word, how is the `return` statement evaluated by the compiler and how do the `?:` *operators* work in this exact example?

**Edit****<sup>*</sup>**: I don't understand the `x.size()` part. Isn't it enough to return the `x[0]` element?

*<sup>*moved from the comments</sup>*

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: The return value is always of type `T*` and if `x.size()` (assuming size returns an integral type) is non-zero, then the value return'd is the first element of `x` else it's `nullptr`.

Comment: I don't understand the x.size() part. Isn't it enough to return the x[0] element? Maybe this is a sanity check, to see if the vector is not empty?

Comment: @tudorarion Yes, if the vector's empty then the container's internal buffer might be `nullptr` in which case `&x[0]` yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: So it's actually return &x[0] if x.size !=0 else nullptr

Comment: Well it's return `return &x[0]` but yes.

Comment: @George that did it, thx, pal!

Comment: Remember, a `ternary` is similar to a short-hand `if else` where you have `test ? if_true_value : if_false_value`. So if `x.size()` tests `true` (e.g. non-zero) then `&x[0]` is returned, otherwise, `nullptr` is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To warp up all the comments made below the question(which supposed to be in the answer section!).

The `begin()` function always return the *pointer to the template type `T`*(i.e. `T*`). The question is what should it return if the passed `std::vector<T>` is empty? Obviously `nullptr`!

That means the equalent `if-else` version is:

```
if(x.size())    // size(unsigend type) can be inplicity converted to bool: true for +ve numbers false for 0 and -ve numbers
  return &x[0]; // return the address of the first element
else
  return nullptr; // return pointer poiting to null
```

---

Remember, that `std::vector` provides the member [`std::vector::empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty). Using it would be much intuitive.

```
if(x.empty()) 
  return nullptr; // if empty
else
  return &x[0];
```

or like in the question, using conditional operator:

```
return x.empty() ? nullptr : &x[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the vector is not empty, returns the address to the first element which is stored in a pointer

Comment: And if the vector is empty, then `nullptr` is returned.

Comment: For me that is a comment and not an answer. It only covers a small part of the question and did not explain anything. If you see other answers on this thread, you see how much more effort is needed to give an answer.